# "Could not authenticate you" error from twitter API

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm using Abhraham's twitter API library.

My index.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
require_once 'twitteroauth/OAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "");
$to = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$tok = $to->getRequestToken("http://mydoamin.com/twitter/redirect.php");
$request_link = $to->getAuthorizeURL($tok);
$_SESSION['oauth_access_token']= $tok['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] = $tok['oauth_token_secret'];
header("Location: $request_link");
exit;
?>
```

My redirect.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
require_once 'twitteroauth/OAuth.php';
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "");

$to=new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,$_SESSION['oauth_access_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret']);
$content = $to->get('account/verify_credentials');
var_dump($content);
?>
```

But I dont understant why I'm getting `"Could not authenticate you"` on the redirect.php page

Comment: Have you confirmed your sesison handling is being retained on the next page?

Comment: Do you really want to be exposing your keys here?

Comment: @iThink Change your Twitter API keys now. Even if they get edited out, it's too late. They're in the edit history, in the Google cache, and in any browser that's already opened this page.

Comment: @Scuzzy yes its retained on the next page

Comment: Try logging into your account on Twitter and revoking permission to your app, then go back, clear your session and try this again. It's been a bit quirky for me too, but this seemed to help.

Comment: @Chris everytime I tried I was logged in twitter. And what do u exactly mean by "revoking permission"?

Comment: @iThink go to http://twitter.com/settings/applications and click 'Revoke Access' next to your app. Then go back and try and login using your script again.

Comment: @Chris ah! I don't see my application there :(

Comment: @iThink It's not that then. I've seen something else though, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this doesn't work because you cannot put `$tok` directly in the `getAuthrorizeURL()` function:

```
$tok = $to->getRequestToken("http://mydoamin.com/twitter/redirect.php");
$request_link = $to->getAuthorizeURL($tok);
```

You need to extract the token from `$tok['oauth_token']`:

```
$tok = $to->getRequestToken("http://mydoamin.com/twitter/redirect.php");
$request_link = $to->getAuthorizeURL($tok['oauth_token']);
```

Let me know if this fixes it.